# Angular and CreateJS not finding the stage element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, easeljs, createjs

I have an Angular view that is inherited from an `ng-view` element.

In the view file, I have a canvas. The code is controlled by a controller. What I want to do is call up a stage to add elements on the canvas.

However when I run the `createJS.Stage` function, a stage is created with everything as `null` and no bounds.

I'm guessing  the element is not getting bound to the stage but I can't figure out why

**index.html**

```
<ng-view     style='height: 100%;'></ng-view>
```

**template.html**

```
<div class='middle' style="min-height:90%;height:90%">
<div class='col-lg-8'>
<canvas id="demoCanvas" class='col-lg-11' style='margin-top:10px'></canvas>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 app.controller('taskController',function($scope,$location,$routeParams,dataFactory){
    var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
    console.log(stage.getBounds()); 
   //bounds turn up as null as well as style and any other function that I run
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out the problem is that the DOM is not completely loaded when an AngularJS  controller is run

The trick to running it once the DOM has finished loading is

```
app.controller('taskController',function($scope,$location,$routeParams,dataFactory){
    $timeout(function(){
        visualInspectionHandler();
    });
    function visualInspectionHandler(){
          var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
          console.log(stage.getBounds()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can access the Canvas as part of the created HTML DOM fragment, you can always pass that as a reference instead of the ID (which simply uses a `document.getElementById` lookup in EaselJS). This is the approach we usually take with Backbone apps: `new createjs.Stage(this.$(".demoCanvas").get(0))`;